# Using CSS - How can I get text to position to the right of an image?

Tags: html, css

Long(ish) time lurker, first time poster! Apologies if this has been asked a 1000 times I am new to coding and I am currently working on a project with Codecademy and I was hoping someone would be able to provide some help...

I am tasked with replicating the layout you can see in the screenshot below. However I am unable to get any further as I cannot for the life of me get text to appear centered and to the right of the image. The closest I have gotten previously is the text will appear to the top right of the image. I am using a file for html and a seperate style sheet if that helps.

[how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcUrq.jpg)

[how mine looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha0bH.png)

This is my HTML code so far

```
<div class="flex-content" id="banner">
        <img class="img2"><img src="images/banner.jpg"></div>
        <div class="supporting-content">
            <h3>Learn something new every day</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><a class="button" href="#">Start here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any guidance would be hugely appreciated!

Alikin

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: You can put the image together with a container for text and buttons in another container and choose ```display: flex``` and set ```justify-content: space-between;``` For the container.

Comment: seems like you havent added any css, you should use css for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use flexbox and "flex-direction: row;"